# All objects in array needs to be affected in my method

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I am creating a pokémon-ish game for a high school project and have a hard time making every object in my array be affected by this method. I want all characters that are fire to take double damage from water attacks.

The problem is that the `attack` method is only functioning on one `character`.

I have found out that only 1 object in the array can be affected, but I want it to be general for every single object and character I make.

My Array

```
    ArrayList<Attacks> attacks;
    ArrayList<Characters> characters;

        attacks = new ArrayList<Attacks>();
        characters = new ArrayList<Characters>();
```

My attack class

```
//Stats--------------
    private int damage;
    private int accuracy;
    private int critChance;

    //Typ----------------------
     boolean fire;
     boolean water;

    public Attacks(int damage , int accuracy , int critChance , boolean fire , boolean water) {
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
        this.critChance = critChance;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.fire = fire;
        this.water = water;
    }
    public boolean isFire(){
        return fire;
    }
    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }
    public boolean isWater(){
        return water;
    }
}
```

My character class

```
//Types
    private boolean fire;
    public int health;

    public Characters(int health, boolean fire) {
        this.health = health;
        this.fire = fire;
        }

    public boolean characterIsFire()
    {
        return fire;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}
```

My constructors for my objects

```
        //Construktor for Characters--------------------

        final Characters fredrik = new Characters(1000 , false);
        characters.add(fredrik);
        final Characters jonte = new Characters(1000 , false);
        characters.add(jonte);

        //Construktor for attacker -------------------
        //Fredriks attacks
        final Attacks fireball = new Attacks(1 , 10 , 10 , false , true);
        attacks.add(fireball);
        final Attacks heatwave = new Attacks(1 , 0 , 10 , true , false);
        attacks.add(heatwave);

        //Jontes attacks
        final Attacks waterball = new Attacks(3 , 0, 4, false , true);
        attacks.add(waterball);
```

My method that I want all characters and attacks to be affected by.

```
    public int attacking(Attacks a) {
        int damage;
        Characters attacked = characters.get(//All the characters in the array);
        if (attacked.characterIsFire() && a.isWater())
        {
            damage = (a.getDamage() * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            damage = a.getDamage();
        }
        return damage;
    }
```

Comment: So you loop over the characters, and call `attacking` on each of them... could you clarify which part is causing problems?

Comment: also: don't mistaker Lists for Arrays. it's not because it has 'Array' in the name, that it is an actual Array

Comment: @JonSkeet I want every character to be affected by the ```attacking``` method. I need help with the code that I have to put in the parentheses in ```Characters attacked = characters.get(//All the characters in the array);```. So the problem is that not every character is affected by this method.

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to loop *inside* your `attacking` method then: `for (Characters attacked : characters) { /* code for each attacked character */ }`. However, the `attacking` method doesn't currently seem to be *modifying* the character at all - it's just returning a single value. It's really unclear what the method is intended to achieve at the moment, I'm afraid, or what it would mean for it to "affect" all characters (when it doesn't change their state anyway).

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry for being so unclear. The attacking method is supposed to deal extra damage depending on the variables of the character and attack. In this case, all attacks that are water should deal double damage to all characters that are fire.

Comment: @Missil3r: But the attacking method doesn't "deal the damage" at all. It doesn't modify anything. It just returns a value - presumably the amount of damage that the attack does. If the attack would do 5 damage to one character and 20 damage to another, what would the method return? I strongly suspect you need to change the design. (At the same time, I'd advise you to rename the classes to singular names, e.g. `Attack`. An instance of `Attacks` doesn't literally represent *multiple* attacks, does it?)